# php upload progress not working, $_SESSION[$key] is empty

Tags: php, ajax, session, file-upload

I am trying to create a progress bar for multiple file i upload to a server!!! I am able to upload the files but when i try to fetch the upload progress information the session array is empty. Please do help!!! Please find below the information:
Firstly my main php page where i upload the files:

```
********************************************Main.php********************************
<?php session_start();?>//top of the page
<div id = "centerMain" align="center">
           <iframe name="targetIframe" src="" style="width:50%;height:30%;position:relative;"></iframe>
                    <div id="addNewBlock" class="emboss blockPart" style="z-index:50000;padding:2%;position:relative;width:50%;left:25%;top:35%;border:1px solid black;">
                     <form method="POST" action="handleItemAddition.php" target="targetIframe" enctype = "multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return checkAndStartUpload()">

<!--VERY IMPORTANT:the hidden element should come first before any element within the form-->  <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" id="hidUpProg" value="upFilesInfo" />                 
 <script type ="text/javascript">


var upProgName = "<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>";
                //alert(document.getElementById("hidUpProg").value);
            </script>
            <div  class="stayLeft">Upload Photo:</div><input style="width:40%;" type="file" name = "itemImage[]" id="fileUp" class = "stayRight" multiple/><br/><br/>  


                    <input type="button" id = "closeBut" style="width:20%;" value = "close" onclick="closeBlock()" class="utsaaBut stayLeft"/>
                    <input type="submit" id = "AddBut" style="width:20%;" value = "Done" class="utsaaBut stayRight"/>                  
                    </form>

                </div>
               </div>
********************************************Main.php********************************
```

find below the javscript function which gets called onSubmit = "checkAndStartUpload()" from above

```
******************************************Javascript function****************************
function checkAndStartUpload()
{
    var tmp = document.getElementById("fileUp");
    if(tmp.files.length == 0)
    {
        alert("No file selected. Kindly select a file");
        return false
    }

    $progressPtr = setInterval(handleProgress,50);
    return true;
}

var it = 0;
function handleProgress()
{
    //alert("handleProgress");
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        //alert("response");
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            //alert("value:"+xmlhttp.responseText["content_length"]);
            var res = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert("Response:"+res);
            it++;
            if(it == 25)
            {
                it = 0;
            clearInterval($progressPtr);
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","handleProgressValue.php",true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.send(upProgName+"=upFilesInfo");
}

******************************************Javascript function*******************
```

Next is the file which returns session value through ajax

```
    ******************************************ajax progress return*******************
<?php

$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") .$_POST[ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")];

if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
    $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
    $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
    echo "Current".$current."$total".$total;
    //echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
}
else {
    echo "100";    //IT ALWAYS RETURNS 100 MEANING$_SESSION[$key] IS ALWAYS EMPTY
}
/*session_start();
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix").$_POST[ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")];
//var_dump($_SESSION[$key]);
$tmp = $_SESSION[$key];
echo $tmp["bytes_processed"];*/

?>
    ******************************************ajax progress return*******************
```

And finally handleItemAddition.php successfully uploads the images.
I also disabled ;session.upload_progress.cleanup = On just for testing purpose so that if upload gets completed fast it should not clear the values.

Still i am getting empty array .

Comment: Try to put `session_start();` at the TOP of every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys sorry i forgot to update. I fixed the issue sometime back.
I had put session_start(); on top of all files but in handleProgressValue.php i had commented it while changing the code once i uncommented it worked.

However when i am uploading 28 files say,  why does
count($_SESSION[$key]["files"])
return increasing values??? It first returned 10 then 17,24,28 and then $_SESSION got unset